# DateTime Format Problem To Get Same Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have some questions about using datetime format.

In one part of project,client pc send their datetime to server.
we need to get those datetime in same format like `dd/MM/yyyy`.

However,client pc use variety of date format,so,they send 
variety of datetime format like this.for eg,

`dd-MM-yyyy`,`dd/MM/yyyy`,`MM-dd-yyyy`,`MM/dd/yyyy`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can the clients not send the date is a constant format such as `yyyy/MM/dd`?

Comment: What kind of client?  What kind of server? (are we talking ASP.NET here?

Comment: our project is window based project.

Comment: So C# win forms posting back to another C# server app?  What is the messaging protocol?

Answer (score 6):

The absolute best way is to not treat date values as strings. They should to the greatest extent possible be treated as `DateTime` values. When doing that, all issues related to formatting disappears. If you have a client where the user enters date format in their local style, convert it to a `DateTime` directly after input, and then send the `DateTime` value into the system.

If you still need to exchange date information in string format, always stick to a standardized format (such as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Comment: +1 ISO 8601 (as used in xs:DateTime) will also be able to handle timezone discrepancies as well.

Comment: i am sure it's datetime because it doesn't get from user.i mean,
all client send system.datetime.now.date,but,that format is depend on their pc datetime format style.

Comment: Wouldn't `System.DateTime.Today` be better way of getting the date?

Comment: yes,it also can,but,both functions return datetime depend on current using format.i mean if your pc datetime format is "dd-MM-yyyy" it returns "14-02-2011" but if your format is "MM-dd-yyyy" it returns "02-14-2011".

Comment: @Indi: `DateTime` does not have formatting internally. When you look at the value in a debugger or output it using `ToString`, it will be presented with a format, but that is not part of the value itself.